# Poor Performance When Calling Query From Another DB on same Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, performance, query-performance

I have 2 databases - both on the same server. Both databases also have their files on the same drives.

When I run a query on it's local DB, it runs in 3 secs.

However, when I run it from the second DB, it takes about 20mins! The only difference here is the Database name added to the FROM clause.

What can I look for to find why this performs so badly? Would statistics play a part?

The query is a **SELECT** one on a **TVF**. Unfortunately I cannot view the TVF as it is 3rd party query and I do not have access.

Comment: Upload the actual execution plans to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/. If the queries use the same objects, I'd expect the same plan as long as the session SET options are the same.

Comment: The XML of the Query Plan is actually 19421 rows so cannot copy/paste

Comment: Why can't you copy+paste? Do you get an error when you try? Failing that post the query and details of the tables involved (specifically the keys and indexes defined). There is no way to properly answer "why is this query slow" without seeing the query (or, preferably for complex queries, a minimal cut-down version that exhibits the same problem) and table+index details or the query plan. Also when you say "on the same server" do you mean in the same instance, or do you have two instances and are connecting them with a linked server setup? That can make a significant difference.

Comment: try running the query with option(recompile) .. also what is the compatibility level of the db that is working fine and the one that is not working fine ? Might be CE issue.

Comment: Yes, 2 SQL server instances running on the one windows server.

Comment: Compatibility levels: 100 and 120 so yes there is a difference here.

Comment: Cannot copy XML plan - get the error "The text submitted is larger than 2MB. We cannot accept plans larger than 2MB at this time."

Comment: Tried OPTION(RECOMPILE) but no change

Comment: I know the query plans would help but as standard practice, what should I be checking? Do I need to check indexes, statistics, data files?

Comment: Start with data base permission,then check index,update statistics.Above all,what is estimated number of rows in slow db.is there any diff ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was the **Compatibility Level** as suggested by @Kin

One database was 120, the other 100.

I updated to ensure both are 120 and now queries are quick on both databases!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database

Thanks all for the help!